# reading line and splitting to char array

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

I can't understand why my program not functioning. It compiles but nothing is printed. I have a 5 character word in file. I need to read line from that file and then split it into char array, which I then want print out.Thanks!

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        BufferedReader line = null;
        char[] array = new char[7];

        try{

            line = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));

            String currentLine;
            while((currentLine = line.readLine()) != null)
            {
                array = currentLine.toCharArray();
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(array[i]);
            }

        }//try

        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            System.err.println(exception);
        }//catch

        finally
        {
            try 
            {
                if(line != null) 
                    line.close();
            }//try

            catch(IOException exception)
            { 
                System.err.println("error!" + exception);
            }//catch

        }//finally
    } // main
} // test
```

Comment: I think your missing a bracket somewhere in there.

Comment: This code works fine when given the described input file. please post your input file if Reimeus's answer does not work for you.

Comment: Tangential to the question at hand, but there's no reason to initialize the `array` variable with a newly allocated array. It just gets thrown away when the variable is set in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop skips every line except the last one so it could be possible that your last line is empty. To display every line you could have:

```
while ((currentLine = line.readLine()) != null) {
    array = currentLine.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Or if you just have the 1 line, You could simply use:

```
String currentLine = line.readLine(); 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program prints only last line

You have to Print in loop.

```
while (....!=null)
{
 array = currentLine.toCharArray();

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   {
      System.out.print(array[i]);
   }


}
```

If above was not a problem than check your file permission.

Check your system may be program is not able to read from file due to permission on file.

Comment: wouldn't an exception be thrown if the file permissions were an issue?